# Send POST when checkbox is ticket - without submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I want to send POST data without submit button, when one of the checkboxes are ticked - USING AJAX.

I have this code, but I think, that when I tick checkbox, I should get an alert with posted data (to know, that its working), but I dont get any reaction at all. I've added jquery so it's some kind of error in code function..

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3</input>
</form>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // jQuery code is in here
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {

    var data = $(this).val();
    console.log(data); // 1, 2 or 3 (value)
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo JURI::getInstance(); ?>", // URL should be correct!
        type: "POST", 
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: {data: data},
        dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
    });

});




</script>
```

PROBLEM: Getting HTML content of page, not value on success method

Comment: You have a success callback function, but you should also have an error callback function. Same way, except instead of `success: function(){alert(data);}` it's `error: function(data)...`

Comment: share `x.php` code also ?

Comment: @Niklesh x.php contains only print_r($_POST); Of course, I get empty array.

Comment: try changing this data: ({data: data}) TO data: {data: data},

Answer (score 0):

Change your Html as below 1. remove `</input>` and change 2. change form `name` to `id`

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3
</form>
```

Change in JS

```
var data = $("#form1").serialize();
```

Your form was not selecting and in post there was blank data

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3</input>
</form>

<script>
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
      var data = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../x.php", // URL should be correct!
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: {data: data},
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(response_data){ 
                alert(response_data);
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Still don't get any alert. Could it be because url is somehow wrong?

Comment: Have you checked in browser console? It will helps to get whats going wrong.

Comment: Console shows 'JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1', but nothing else appears when I tick checkboxes

Comment: I have updated my answer from "checked" event to "click" event. Please try with that and check your console..

Comment: Ahh have you included jquery file? :)

Comment: @JohnCoolGuy1996 : what value you are getting in `alert(data)`  after line `var data = $("form").serialize();` ?

Comment: @Niklesh I do not get that far. I get error - Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: include this jquery file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @ Harsh - Everything is fine now. I updated original POST. I get checked checkbox id in 'data' variable, but I still cant get post data on success method. :/

Comment: In Chrome You can see your data in Network->XHR mode and in FF you can see in Net->XHR. First make sure you get the data in XHR mode.

Comment: Harsh - I do get data. On every tick, smth like this: Array ( [data] => checkboxList%5B%5D=3 )

Comment: Of course it gives data on every click. And Is this full result which is generated at the time of click on any checkbox? I think you should use "var data = $(this).val();" instead of "var data = $("form").serialize();" try with this one.

Comment: @HarshBarach data now has cleaner values like (1 or 2 ect..), but I still do not get data not in the x.php (when I do print_r($_POST) - its null) ) nor on alert - as I should, huh?

Comment: Now, you need to return some data from x.php after that you can get data in Ajax response.

Comment: @HarshBarach Can u give me an example? I updated orignal post. Now on success method, data gives me HTML content of page (weird). Shouldn't it be the value of checked checkbox? Also, x.php print_r($_POST) is null. :/